# I have two Facebook accounts and would like to delete one of them

Tags: facebook

I noticed I have two Facebook account but I would like to know how to delete one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can permanently delete your Facebook account by following the instructions on the [Facebook support site](https://www.facebook.com/help/224562897555674):

> If you don't think you'll use Facebook again, you can request to have
>   your account permanently deleted. Please keep in mind that you won't
>   be able to reactivate your account or retrieve anything you've added.
>   Before you do this, you may want to [download a copy of your info](https://www.facebook.com/help/212802592074644) from
>   Facebook. Then, if you'd like your account permanently deleted with no
>   option for recovery, log into your account and [let us know](https://www.facebook.com/help/delete_account).
>
> When you delete your account, people won't be able to see it on
>   Facebook. It may take up to 90 days to delete all of the things you've
>   posted, like your photos, status updates or other data stored in
>   backup systems. While we are deleting this information, it is
>   inaccessible to other people using Facebook.
>
> Some of the things you do on Facebook aren’t stored in your account.
>   For example, a friend may still have messages from you even after you
>   delete your account. That information remains after you delete your
>   account.